# Simplificar forEach para atualizar um doc do mongoDB que tem objetos e arrays aninhados

Tags: javascript, json, array, mongodb, desempenho

Eu quero atualizar o valor da chave 'shouldSendAlert' em um documento do mongoDB que está na seguinte estrutura:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c61c4db46d18e1092c5b024"),
    "service" : "SRVPVD",
    "menu" : [ 
        {
            "sub" : [ 
                {
                    "options" : [ 
                        {
                            "item" : [ 
                                {
                                    "name" : "",
                                    "actions" : [ 
                                        {
                                            "name" : "communicateClient",
                                            "value" : true
                                        }, 
                                        {
                                            "name" : "shouldSendAlert",
                                            "value" : false
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "name" : "Technology Support"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "item" : [ 
                                {
                                    "name" : "",
                                    "actions" : [ 
                                        {
                                            "name" : "communicateClient",
                                            "value" : true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "name" : "Company Support"
                        }
                    ],
                    "name" : "Support"
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : " FAQ"
                }
            ],
            "name" : "Help"
        }
    ]
}
```

Eu consegui atingir esse objetivo, com uma query $elemMatch múltipla e usando um forEach para cada array dentro do JSON para chegar ao 'shouldSendAlert':

```
{
    let menuItems = db.getCollection('menumodels').find({menu: {$elemMatch: {name: 'Help',sub: {$elemMatch: {name: 'Support',motivos: {$elemMatch: {name: 'Technology Support'}}}}}}});

    menuItems.forEach((r) => {
        r.menu.forEach(menuItem => {
            if (menuItem.name == 'Help') {
                menuItem.sub.forEach(sub => {
                    if (sub.name == 'Support') {
                        sub.motivos.forEach(motivo => {
                            if (motivo.name == "Technology Support") {
                                motivo.item[0].actions.forEach(action => {
                                    if (action.name == 'shouldSendAlert') {
                                        action.value = true;
                                        db.getCollection('menumodels').update({_id: r._id}, {$set: {menu: r.menu}})
                                    }
                                })
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    });
}
```

É necessário, em questão de performance, fazer essa operação de uma forma mais inteligente? Usar todos estes $elemMatch e forEach dentro de forEach, impacta a performance de forma significativa?

Obrigado pelas dicas.

Comment: Não entendi bem, mas seria algo assim? estrutura.menu.find(x => x.name === 'Help').sub.find(x => x.name === 'Support').options.find(x => x.name === 'Technology Support').item[0].actions.find(x => x.name === 'shouldSendAlert').value = true;

Comment: @RDyego, como mencionei na pergunta, o código funciona. Se você reparar na linha

`db.getCollection('menumodels').find({menu: {$elemMatch: {name: 'Help',sub: {$elemMatch: {name: 'Support',motivos: {$elemMatch: {name: 'Technology Support'}}}}}}});` 

A query me retorna um array com o documento esperado. 

Quero saber se ele precisa ser refatorado por motivos de performance. Por exemplo: usar multiplos $elemMatch aninhados, é muito custoso?

Comment: São 5 forEach´s aninhados, isso é bem complexo. Ate para manutenção não é simples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se o mongoDB tem funções que ajudem neste caso, mas podes fazer uma função que procure um caminho num objeto e fazer retornar o valor que encontrar.

No exemplo que criei em baixo juntei um argumento que costumo usar para ter um ponteiro de um objeto criado por mim para ter a certeza que a busca falhou. Nota que nesta função, caso o resultado que procures seja `undefined` e isso seja um resultado que queres retornar a função tem de ser ajustada. Mas no caso que mostras na pergunta isto faz o que procuras.

```js
const complexObject = {
  foo: [{
    bar: 'baz',
    nestedFoo: {
      hello: 'world'
    }
  }]
};

function findPathValue(obj, path, noValue) {
  return path.split('.').reduce((value, key) => {
    const keyValue = value[key];
    return typeof keyValue === 'undefined' ? noValue : keyValue;
  }, obj);
};
const noResult = {};

const willFind = findPathValue(complexObject, 'foo.0.nestedFoo.hello', noResult);
const willFail = findPathValue(complexObject, 'foo.bar.baz', noResult);

console.log(willFind, willFind === noResult); // world false
console.log(willFail, willFail === noResult); // {} true
```

Comment: Mas e no caso de não saber a posição do array que tem o valor que eu quero?
O mongoDB permite usar o wildCard ```*``` apenas uma vez por query. Nesse caso não vou ter como escapar do forEach, não é?

Comment: @MatheusPedro O `forEach` nunca é bom neste caso. Deves usar quanto muito o `.find()` ou `.some()`. Se não sabes a posição na array qual é a referência? a chave? mas alguns objetos na mesma array têm a mesma chave...

Comment: a referência é o valor da chave ```name```.

Comment: @MatheusPedro então nesse caso queres saber se um dado objeto tem dentro uma chave com um valor específico. É isso?

Comment: exatamente! Além disso, quero também mudar o valor desta chave. Eu consegui fazer isso, mas tive que usar um monte de ```forEach```. Nesse caso, acho que poderia usar o ```.find()``` para me dizer o indice que quero em cada array, pra depois alterar o valor de ```shouldSendAlert```usando um ```db.getCollection('menumodels').update``` simples.